# How to count the number of vowels, consonants, and characters in a string using react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to count the number of consonants/vowels/characters depending on the user's given word, then the result is displayed on the screen. I have tried to solve however it still didn't show up

```js
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
      this.state ={
        value: '',
        consonant: 0,
        vowels: 0,
        characters:0,
      }
  }

  WordAnalyzer = () => {
    this.setState({value: this.state.value}),
    () => {

      const listVowel=['a','i','u','e','o','A','I','U','E','O'];
      let arr_word= this.state.value.split('');
      for (let j=0; j<arr_word.length; j++){
        for (let i=0; i< listVowel.length; i++){
          if (arr_word[j] == listVowel[i]){
            this.setState({vowels: this.state.vowels + 1});
          }
          else{
            this.setState({consonant: this.state.consonant +1});
          }
        }
        this.setState({characters: this.state.characters +1});
      }
    };
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Word Analyzer</Text>
        <TextInput style= {styles.input} onChangeText={(value) =>this.setState({value})} placeholder='Input a word here' />
        <Button color = '#841584' onPress={this.WordAnalyzer} title='Analyze'/>
        <Text>Word            :   {this.state.value}</Text>
        <Text>No of Consonants:   {this.state.consonant}</Text>
        <Text>No of Vowels    :   {this.state.vowels}</Text>
        <Text>No of Characters:   {this.state.characters}</Text>
      </View>     
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be alot less work (for both you and your computer) if you were to simply use `match` on the string to figure out how many vowels and consonants are in it.

And, of course, you can simply use `this.state.value.length` to get the number of characters.

Thus, WordAnalyzer can be refactored into the much simpler:

```
    WordAnalyzer = () => {
        const vowelsCount = this.state.value.match(/[AaEeIiOoUu]/g).length;
        this.setState({
            characters: this.state.value.length,
            vowels: vowelsCount,
            consonant: this.state.value.match(/[a-zA-z]/g).length - vowelsCount
        });
    };
```

Comment: You can also add a `i` flag in there and reduce the size of your capture group for `vowelsCount` by half